# Как использовать char непосредственно в уравнении?

Tags: java, char

Можно ли использовать char символ в качестве знака в уравнении? 
Пример:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayList<Character> chatList = new ArrayList<>();
  chatList.add('+');
  chatList.add('-');
  Integer i = 25 + chatList.get(0) + 25;
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

Результат : `93`.

Почему 93, я понимаю.(потому что символ `+` равен 43 в таблице ASCII).

Так вот вопрос как использовать этот символ как символ, а не число?

Варианты

```
if(chatList.get(0)=='+'){}
```

не рассматривать.

Comment: `switch` + `case`

Comment: Можете строить полную строку выражения и написать интерпретатор выражений(лексер, парсер и т.п.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В арифметических вычислениях `char` автоматически приводится к `int`.

Если нет цели написать свой интерпретатор, можно сделать через `String` с помощью скриптового движка https://stackoverflow.com/a/3423360/8830684

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
StringBuilder expr = new StringBuilder();
expr.append(25);
expr.append(chatList.get(0));
expr.append(25);
System.out.println(engine.eval(expr.toString()));
```

Соответствующие классы нужно импортировать.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/210733)

Comment: Добавил пример кода в ответ.

Comment: Теперь лучше ^_^